# Read properties file in Spring Boot

Tags: properties, spring-boot

How could I read properties form a separate file in Spring Boot ?

I'm trying what he's doing here.. http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-propertysources-example/

But it doesn't read the file?

say you have a file.properties in the resources folder.

you should put :

```
  spring.configuration.location: classpath:file.properties
```

in application.properties to point to the file.

Then in your MyConfig class

```
@Service
public class MyConfig{

    @Value("${prop.one}")
    private String propOne;
```

Shouldn't this work? what am I doing wrong

Is there a simple example of doing this somewhere?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to create an `application.properties` that will reside at the root of your jar

```
src
  main
    resources
      application.properties
```

Spring boot will autoload this file as a properties file. This is a special feature of spring boot to look for the application.properties automatically. With regular Spring, you need to specify where the properties file is. They are demonstrating how to add a new properties file with regular spring.

For a separate properties file from the standard application.properties, you can add the [@PropertySource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html) annotation to your configuration class. This annotation will load the properties into the spring environment.

Comment: Yes I've seen that this works but how to have a separate properties file ? Is it because it's Spring Boot that that's not possible ?

Comment: Ah ok. Just trying to give the easy way first. I added the annotation that you need to use for a second properties file.